# How much is paid for a Selenium Automation Tester who has an overall experience of 3 years?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, manual-testing

Currently I am working in a selenium automated project and I look for a jump to get paid more.I have an experience of 2 years in selenium automation.
I Just want to know how much salary I should ask as my current CTC of 3.5 lakh Indian Rupee.

Comment: Too narrow -- will not be of general interest

Answer (score 5):

There's no real answer here. You should ask whatever your specific skills will command in your specific market, and for the specific job you are seeking.

Explore local job sites to see what is being offered in similar positions.

If there is an equivalent for salary.com in your part of the world, look there.